# I am trying to implment Devise concept on rails I get Error like

Tags: devise

DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:9:in `<class:FailureApp>': uninitialized constant ActionController::RackDelegation (NameError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:8:in`'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:121:in`default_failure_app'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in`new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `add_mapping'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in`block in devise_for'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in`devise_for'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in`instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in`draw'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`block in load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in`block in updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in`updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:116:in`block in '
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in`block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in`tsort_each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in`preload'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in`block in run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in`'
lt-48@lt48-Vostro-1015:~/Desktop/DeviceDemo$ rails generate devise:view
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:9:in `<class:FailureApp>': uninitialized constant ActionController::RackDelegation (NameError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:8:in`'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:121:in`default_failure_app'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in`new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `add_mapping'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in`block in devise_for'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in`devise_for'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in`instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in`draw'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`block in load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in`block in updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in`updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:116:in`block in '
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in`block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
lt-48@lt48-Vostro-1015:~/Desktop/DeviceDemo$ rails generate devise:views
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from require at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:77)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:9:in `<class:FailureApp>': uninitialized constant ActionController::RackDelegation (NameError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:8:in`'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:121:in`default_failure_app'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in`new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in `add_mapping'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in`block in devise_for'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in`devise_for'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in`instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in`draw'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`block in load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in`block in updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in`updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:116:in`block in '
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in`block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in`tsort_each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
        from /home/lt-48/Desktop/DeviceDemo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in`preload'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in`block in run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in`'